# Scala program to display the output in format below

Tags: scala

Find the missing code in the Scala program to display the output in the following format.

Output:

```
Array[(Int, String)] = Array((4,anar), (5,applelichi), (6,bananagrapes), (7,oranges))
```

Program

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List("apple","banana","oranges","grapes","lichi","anar"))

val b = a.map(x =>(x.length,x))
```

Comment: what is the variable `sc`? Are you using spark?

Comment: it seems like you are using stackoverflow to solve your homework. You should try to reach the solution by yourself. If you can't, feel free to make the question, but explain what have you tried so far

Comment: yeah my bad sorry. wont post more question( not exactly homework though )

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will give you the wanted result:

```
a.groupBy(_.length).mapValues(_.sorted.mkString).toArray.sorted
```

Comment: i have few more question in scala can you please help.

Comment: @user9687264 if this answer is right please accept it.
I couldnt see any other questions in your profile

Comment: Find the missing code in the Scala program to display the output in the following format.

Output: Array((h,(None,Some(12))), (a,(Some(2),None)), (b,(Some(5),None)), (c,(Some(4),None)), (d,(Some(12),None)), (e, (None,Some(2))), (f,(None,Some(5))), (g,(None,Some(4))))

Program

val a = sc.parallelize(List(("a",2),("b",5),("c",4),("d",12)))

val b = sc.parallelize(List(("e",2),("f",5),("g",4),("h",12)))

<Write your code>

Comment: @user9687264 please create a new question,
Seems like we are solving your homework or something....

Comment: shaish can't create new question "after 90 mins rule". Its my simulation test for big data , today is the last date to submit my solutions and i have 0 knowledge on scala. i wasted like 250$ on this course atleast i will get certification if i complete test

Comment: That would be a faulty certification if you still "have 0 knowledge" of Scala.

Comment: yeah sorry wont post more question.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `reduceByKey`

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List("apple","banana","oranges","grapes","lichi","anar"))
val b = a.map(x =>(x.length,x)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

which should give you

```
b: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)] = ....
//(4,anar)
//(6,bananagrapes)
//(7,oranges)
//(5,applelichi)
```